# std::floating_point concept in CUDA for all IEE754 types

Tags: c++, cuda, precision, c++-concepts, half-precision-float

I would like to know if CUDA provides a concept similar to `std::floating_point` but including all IEE754 types including e.g. __half. I provide below a sample code that test that __half template functions do not compile with `std::floating_point`.

```
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda_fp16.h>

template<std::floating_point T>
__host__ __device__ bool use_floating_point() {
    return True;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "Is float a floating-point type?" << use_floating_point<float>() << '\n';
  std::cout << "Is __half a floating-point type?" << use_floating_point<__half>() << '\n'; // Compilation error
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::floating_point` is only for a rather limited set of types, you want [`std::is_iec559`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_iec559), which is true for all floating point types that full fill `IEE754`. Though I dont know if it actually matches `__half`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Doesn't look like it: https://godbolt.org/z/bnr6WPM5P (nvidia/standard library authors would have to specialize `std::numeric_limits<__half>` which it doesn't look like they do. `__half` is a class type with `operator+`/etc defined to act like a scalar type)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [`std::is_iec559`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_iec559), because `is_floating_point` covers only a limited set of types, while `is_iec559`, to my understanding is supposed to match any type that implements IEE754.

However, as @Artyer points out in a comment. `std::is_iec559<__half>` is `false`.

If you merely need `std::is_flaoting_point` plus `__half`, you can write your custom concept

```
template <typename T>
concept floating_or_half = std::floating_point<T> || std::same_as<T,__half>;


template<floating_or_half T>
bool use_floating_point() {
    return true;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xrPjG613f)

Comment: I did not know of std::is_iec559 indeed. std::float16_t is in the std::is_iec559 so I guess this would still work if CUDA integrates the C++23 standard in the future.